# Invalid escaped json response from micronaut-graphql when use with micronaut-function-aws-api-proxy

Tags: graphql, micronaut, micronaut-aws

The graphql endpoint return the following invalid json response:

```
[
    "{\"data\":{\"findById\":{\"lastName\":\"Doe\",\"firstName\":\"John\",\"gender\":\"MALE\"}}}"
]
```

The correct one should be:

```
{
    "data": {
        "findById": {
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "firstName": "John",
            "gender": "MALE"
        }
    }
}
```

I created a github repo and raised an issue at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-aws/issues/392 11 days ago, so far no one response, hence I post the question here.

Anyone face similar issue?

Thanks in advance for your helpful response.

Comment: Anyone here have any idea?

Comment: Try to downgrade to latest stable version. What about version 1.3.6 , does it work ?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I downgraded micronaut version to 1.2.11 then it only works, as per my response 12 days ago in the github issue reported above.